# Is RAM usage of IPC a part of the RAM usage of a program

Tags: linux-kernel, ps, top, ram, ipc

I'm learning how to use Message Queue in Linux and I've found a simple example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ipc-using-message-queues/.

With the reader and writer in this link, I can read and write messages through the Message Queue on my Ubuntu. Everything is fine.

Well, if I'm right, when we write some messages into a Message Queue, the messages are stored into the Kernel, meaning that the Kernel will allocate some RAM to store them.

Let's say I keep writing many messages into a Message Queue but never consume them. As my understanding, more and more RAM will be used. In this case, can I use the command `top` or `ps aux` to monitor the increasing usage of RAM?

The lines `VIRT` and `RES` of the command `top` are about RAM usage and the lines `VSZ` and `RSS` of the command `ps aux` are about RAM usage too.

In the case above, can I see some of the four numbers (`VIRT`, `RES`, `VSZ` and `RSS`) are increasing? Or `top` and `pa aux` can't show us the RAM usage of the Kernel, which is used by MQ, FIFO, SHM, domain socket or other IPC ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPC resources aren’t tied to a given process, so they don’t show up in the data displayed by `top`, `ps` etc. You can see this in the example you’re referring to: the message queue is created by the writer but deleted by the reader.

To monitor IPC resources, you can use `lsipc`:

```
lsipc
```

will provide an overview, and

```
lsipc -q
```

will show details of the message queues.